# How to make Multiply / divide sql tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make multiplication in web shop that will show real price:

**discount * tax * product price * 1 piece= real price**

My tables names:

**Table "Products" - Structure "Product_price"** // That is Product price (it's normal number)

**Table " _config" / Param "tax"** // That is Tax (it's percent (%))

**Table " Products" / Structure "Product_discount"** // That is Discount (it's percent (%))

And I need after calculation to make it visible in table, something like this `'<td>'.$realprice.'</td>'.`

// I try to add this line: `$sql = 'select sum( preco * (1 - desconto /100) *1 )AS total FROM Products');` but without success.

- preco means Price
- descont means discount

Sorry for bad english...

Comment: What does without success mean? Is it telling you there's an error with the SQL, or is it returning the wrong amount? Or nothing at all?

Comment: It happens that can not open the page, just displays blank page. When I change "$sql" to "$something" and change code to $something=$adb->Execute($sql. 'SELECT * , sum( preco * (1 - desconto /100) *1 )AS total FROM Products'); then show nothing.

Comment: Are `error_reporting` and `display_errors` turned on?

Comment: Have you tried running your query straight in the database to make sure it works?

Comment: When turn on display_errors this appears: Fatal error: Call to a member function RecordCount() on a non-object in .../public_html/inc/Products.php on line 133 --- on line 133 I have: if($rs->RecordCount()>0) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a SUM aggregate if you want to get the "real price" for each product, for each row in the Products table.

```
   SELECT preco * (1 - desconto /100.0) AS total FROM Products
```

Also, if `desconto` is integer type, you want to be sure that you don't get an integer division operation when dividing by 100.  By specifying `100.0`, that's a decimal literal, rather than integer.  (I don't see any tax calculation in there either, with a tax rate, it would be something like this...

```
   SELECT preco * (1-desconto/100.0) * (1-taxrate/100.0) AS total FROM Products
```

You may also want to apply a ROUND function on that, to eliminate fractional cents or whatever, probably after you multiply by your quantity (which is omitted in my example).

Comment: Thanks, this work, but when I open product page, page is blank and show: Fatal error: Call to a member function RecordCount() on a non-object in */public_html/inc/Product.php on line 133, on line 133 to 144 I have:`if($rs->RecordCount()>0) {$odd = true;$prod = new Produto(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);`This is what I put in php on line 122 `$sql='SELECT * , sum( preco * (1 - desconto /100) ) '` But of course this is no longer a problem for this topic and thanks again.